# Partial derevative and saddle point

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus, optimization, hessian-matrix

${H_{f(x,y)}} = \left[ \begin{array}{l}
{f_{xx}}\,\,\,\,\,{f_{xy}}\,\\
{f_{yx}}\,\,\,\,{f_{yy}}
\end{array} \right]$

In the case of $\Delta_2=f_{xx}f_{yy}−(f_{xy})^2<0$, does $(x,y)$ satisfying  $f_{xx}f_{yy}>0$ exist?

Comment: Consider $f=x^2+y^2+10xy$.

Comment: thank you very match